# have to call the native client method after node loaded?

Tags: google-nativeclient

For example, a embed node like this:

```
document.createElement('embed');
ctrlEmbed.setAttribute('id', moduleid);
ctrlEmbed.setAttribute('src', 'xx.nmf');
ctrlEmbed.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-pnacl');
node.addEventListener('load', moduleDidLoad, true);
```

And the moduleDidLoad Function is:

```
function moduleDidLoad()
{
    ctrlMoudle = document.getElementById(moduleid);
}
```

As the Native Client develop guide say,If you want get the handle of native client module,you must call document.getElementById(moduleid) in the callback function of 'load' event.
My question is, can i just call document.getElementById(moduleid) after i create the  element?I've tried but failed.Do i have to call document.getElementById(moduleid) after the  is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById can't locate an item in the document unless it's already been added into the document (document.body.appendChild etc).
createElement creates an unattached DOM object.

This behavior is independent of NaCl.

Comment: i've already call the appendChild,but failed again.you mean that if i call appendChild(element),the element will be load immediately?

Comment: and if i call var module = getelementbyid(//nacl app id) after appendchild,i call postMessageAndWait,the error is "Uncaught Error: Attempted to call a synchronous method on a plugin that was not yet loaded".